# How to horizontally align text in rows below rotated text?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, rotating

I have a table with rotated text in the uppermost columns, however in certain rows the X's are not horizontally centered.  I thought that having the \centering or perhaps the origin=c command would fix this, but it hasn't.

Here is what the table looks like:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.0535cm}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.450cm}}
\newcommand\RotTextTwo[1]{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\vspace{-.4\ht\strutbox}\centering#1}}}
\newcommand\RotTextThree[1]{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\vspace{-.15\ht\strutbox}\centering#1}}}


\begin{table}[t]\caption{This is a table I am using}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|G|U|U|G|U|G|G|G|U|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Some Text} \\ 
\cline{2-10}

Bunch of Text & \RotTextTwo{Garbage Text} & \RotTextThree{Garbage Text Garbage} & \RotTextThree{Garbage Text Garbage} & \RotTextTwo{Garbage Text} & 
\RotTextThree{Garbage Text Garbage} & \RotTextTwo{Garbage Text} & \RotTextTwo{Garbage Text} & \RotTextTwo{Garbage Text} & \RotTextThree{Garbage TextGarbage } \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 2} & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 3} & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 4} & 
& X & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 5} & 
& X &   X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 6} & 
& X & X & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 7} & 
& X & X & & & & & & \\
\hline                      
\textit{Meaningless 8} & 
& & & & & & X & & \\
\hline      
\textit{Meaningless Text 9} & 
& & & X & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless 10} & 
& & & X & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 11} & 
& & & & & & & X & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless 12} & 
& & & & X   & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 13} &
& & & & X   & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless 14} & 
& & & & & & & & X \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:nada}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of your machinations could be removed.  The key was to modify the length `\tabcolsep` to narrow the columns.  I now use simple `c` columns, no `\vspace`s nor separate `\RotText` versions, etc.

REVISED to retain OP's desired column widths.  I added `2\tabcolsep` = `12pt` to the `G` and `U` column widths, as defined by the OP, but then set `\tabcolsep` to `0pt`.  Hopefully, the result retains the widths desired by the OP, while centering the columns properly.  Note: I did have to reinsert 6pt around column 1, in order to recover original look, since it was neither a `G` nor `U` column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr.0535cm+12pt\relax}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr.450cm+12pt\relax}}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\centering#1}}}
\begin{table}[t]\caption{This is a table I am using}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|@{\hspace{6pt}}c@{\hspace{6pt}}|G|U|U|G|U|G|G|G|U|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Some Text} \\ 
\cline{2-10}
Bunch of Text & \RotText{Garbage Text} & \RotText{Garbage Text Garbage} & \RotText{Garbage Text Garbage} & \RotText{Garbage Text} & 
\RotText{Garbage Text Garbage} & \RotText{Garbage Text} & \RotText{Garbage Text} & \RotText{Garbage Text} & \RotText{Garbage TextGarbage } \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 2} & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 3} & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 4} & 
& X & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 5} & 
& X &   X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 6} & 
& X & X & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 7} & 
& X & X & & & & & & \\
\hline                      
\textit{Meaningless 8} & 
& & & & & & X & & \\
\hline      
\textit{Meaningless Text 9} & 
& & & X & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless 10} & 
& & & X & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 11} & 
& & & & & & & X & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless 12} & 
& & & & X   & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 13} &
& & & & X   & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless 14} & 
& & & & & & & & X \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:nada}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER, using variable width columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\begin{document}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\centering#1}}}
\begin{table}[t]\caption{This is a table I am using}
\footnotesize
\centering
\let\svtabcolsep\tabcolsep
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Some Text} \\ 
\cline{2-10}

Bunch of Text & \RotText{Garbage Text} & \RotText{Garbage Text Garbage} & \RotText{Garbage Text Garbage} & \RotText{Garbage Text} & 
\RotText{Garbage Text Garbage} & \RotText{Garbage Text} & \RotText{Garbage Text} & \RotText{Garbage Text} & \RotText{Garbage TextGarbage } \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 2} & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 3} & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 4} & 
& X & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 5} & 
& X &   X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 6} & 
& X & X & & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 7} & 
& X & X & & & & & & \\
\hline                      
\textit{Meaningless 8} & 
& & & & & & X & & \\
\hline      
\textit{Meaningless Text 9} & 
& & & X & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless 10} & 
& & & X & & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 11} & 
& & & & & & & X & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless 12} & 
& & & & X   & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless Text 13} &
& & & & X   & & & & \\
\hline
\textit{Meaningless 14} & 
& & & & & & & & X \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:nada}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however I need to specify columns widths manually for my purposes.

Comment: @sphere Please see revision.  Your original definition of a `G` column as 0.0535cm doesn't make sense, which is why you needed `\vspace` corrections.  So what I did was to specify the column widths to what you actually want them, while setting `\tabcolsep` to 0pt.